# React Native Image Picker not configures

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

I'm trying to install [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker) to my React-native project, I have configured as the documentation suggests; As the example suggests; I tried reinstall Android Studio (3.1 and 3.2); I download all APIs and All Tools; Nothing solves the problem:

```
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

> Configure project :app 
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-image-picker'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-image-picker:classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools:common:25.2.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/25.2.3/common-25.2.3.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/common/25.2.3/common-25.2.3.jar
     Required by:
         project :react-native-image-picker > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3
         project :react-native-image-picker > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:25.2.3
         project :react-native-image-picker > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:25.2.3
         project :react-native-image-picker > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:25.2.3
         project :react-native-image-picker > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:25.2.3
         project :react-native-image-picker > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools:sdklib:25.2.3 > com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:25.2.3
         project :react-native-image-picker > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools:sdklib:25.2.3 > com.android.tools:dvlib:25.2.3
         project :react-native-image-picker > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools:sdklib:25.2.3 > com.android.tools:repository:25.2.3

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 9s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "MyTestApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "react": "16.6.1",
    "react-native": "0.57.5",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.27.1",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^5.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.49.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Something wrong?

UPDATED

my build.graddle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your `android/build.gradle` and `android/app/build.gradle` files?

Comment: Just updated @AnonymousSB

Comment: Okay, I suspect I know the issue, I'll provide an answer below.

Comment: Hello All Update your all node module package which getting error like "react-native-image-picker" open this android projectin android studio and update gradle in individual-individual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android packages have their own build tools dependencies and this can cause errors like this. The best solution is to modify your `android/build.gradle` and `android/app/build.gradle` to overwrite the subprojects to use the same build tools as the one your app uses.

#### android/build.gradle

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.1"
}
buildscript {
    ... Keep this the same ...
}
subprojects { subproject ->
    afterEvaluate{
        if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### android/app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    ... whatever else you have here ...
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot! I spent three days looking for it!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest version of `react-native-image-picker` (`0.27.2` at the time of writing) seems to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update your all node module package which getting error like "react-native-image-picker" 
open this android project in android studio and update
gradle in individual-individual

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}
```

it will be help you.